# How do I show advertisements in a blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, ads

I want to show advertisements in my app.
How to add advertisement to my project?
What are the steps i have to follow to integrate it into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to decide on a couple of things. Do you want to host your own ad server? Or would you rather use a service? If you want to use a third-party service, what sort of features do you need? The benefit to using an existing provider is that they'll generally give you some code to take care of inserting the ads. Before you decide on one, check out their SDK to make sure it will provide you with the sort of functionality your app will need.

If you want to make your own, which unless you already have an advertising platform with plenty of clients I would advise against, you'll have to do a couple of things. Create a web service that will allow your app to communicate with the ad server so you can pull ads, track clicks, etc. Then you'll probably need to create some sort of SDK of your own for it so you can reuse it throughout the app, and over multiple apps if you choose.